# Pandas split a column in a DF based on a condition and write back to the column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I need to split a column in a dataframe by '-', keep the last part if '-' exists or keep the original input including Nan and write back to the dataframe. This column may contain '-' and 'np.NaN', how do I achieve the goal?
code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#sample df
data = [[1, '1010'], [2, 'CORP-1030'], [3, 'LLC-1020'], [4, np.NaN],[5, '1040']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'Sector'])

   ID     Sector
0   1       1010
1   2  CORP-1030
2   3   LLC-1020
3   4        NaN
4   5       1040
```

This is what I came up with, NOT clean and readable, looking for a better solution.

```
df[['Sector Name', 'Sector Code']] = df['Sector'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split("-")))
df.drop(['Sector Name'], errors='ignore', inplace=True, axis=1)
df['Sector Code'].fillna(df['Sector'], inplace=True)
df.drop('Sector', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Desired output:

```
   ID      Sector
0   1        1010
1   2        1030
2   3        1020
3   4         NaN
4   5        1040
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fairly simple with `str` accessor

```
df['new'] = df['Sector'].str.split('-').str[-1]
```

Result

```
   ID     Sector   new
0   1       1010  1010
1   2  CORP-1030  1030
2   3   LLC-1020  1020
3   4        NaN   NaN
4   5       1040  1040
```

Comment: Then drop Sector Col and rename new to Sector?

Comment: No need simply use `Sector` in place of `new`: `df['Sector'] = df['Sector'].str.split('-').str[-1]`

Comment: Warning on a real dataframe.   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: I know what went wrong, it is the datatype. I converted 'sector' to str in real dataframe, and now I am able to use split

Answer (score 0):

With simple regex replacement to substitute a leading part followed by `-`:

```
df['Sector'] = df['Sector'].str.replace(r'^[^-]+-', '', regex=True)
```

---

```
   ID Sector
0   1   1010
1   2   1030
2   3   1020
3   4    NaN
4   5   1040
```

Comment: This is what I get on a real dataframe, A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: @LiuYu, I get no errors on pandas `1.5.2`

Comment: My pd.__version__ is 1.3.5, could be the problem. thanks